"Bus error" When importing tensorflow into python
When trying to import tensorflow into a python script I get the following error: "Bus Error". I am using Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS, tensorboard 2.13.0 and, tensorflow 2.13.1. (For a full picture) This runs on a le-potato.
I have tried running the code under GDB and got the following output:
Starting program: /usr/bin/python3 detect_video.py
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0xfffff5c8f120 (LWP 1148)]
[New Thread 0xfffff547f120 (LWP 1149)]
[New Thread 0xfffff0c6f120 (LWP 1150)]
BFD: /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/../../libtensorflow_framework.so.2: .gnu.version_r invalid entry
Error while reading shared library symbols for /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/../../libtensorflow_framework.so.2:
Can't read symbols from /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/../../libtensorflow_framework.so.2: bad value

Thread 1 "python3" received signal SIGBUS, Bus error.
strcmp () at ../sysdeps/aarch64/strcmp.S:136
136     ../sysdeps/aarch64/strcmp.S: No such file or directory.

Looking through this I have tried:

reinstalling tensorflow twice.
Updating the system
Rebooting


The "Bus error" might be related to a compatibility issue with the TensorFlow version.consider reinstalling TensorFlow, ensuring compatibility with Python 3.10, using a virtual environment for ARM. Also, try different TensorFlow versions.
